# The revEng command now requires a provider. What should be passed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

After upgrading from ASP.NET 5 beta5 to beta6 I see that ef revEng now requires an additional argument called provider. The help describes the argument as "The assembly name of the provider" which only has me guessing. What is revEng looking for here?

[image: ef reveEng help]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is looking for the dll that is providing the database.

For example, if you are using sql server, you would insert EntityFramework.SqlServer into that parameter.

For it to work however, make sure you include both EntityFramework.SqlServer and EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design in the project.json